# Ungrab KivyMD Slider if slide vertically

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i need when i slide vertically in terminal says out then the touch release by it self automatically,how to do that in kivymd?

Look at the picture im using right click and slide it vertically but the touch was still hold and didnt release or ungrab by itself

[Condition when slide vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg7CR.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you clarify what the problem is? Because I am not sure whether the problem is with slider or you are not able to access terminal when the slider is being displayed.

Comment: i dont want user can slide vertically so when user slide vertically the slider back to default position,its like spotify mobile app when i slide vertically the slider going back to the last position